# How to click a radio button on a webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to automate a bunch of repetitive tasks in a web application from Invisalign (for tooth alignment). Every time I submit a case for alteration, there are 4 clicks (3 buttons and 1 radio) which must be made, followed by a page reload and another two clicks.

I have the clicks worked out alright but I am struggling with the radio button. For the first button I am using the following:

```
document.querySelector("button[type='button'][data-qa-name='approve-proceed-button']").click();
```

Once that is clicked a radio button must be selected. I am attempting to change data-qa-checked= from "false" to "true" (see below)

```
<div class=-"c012081"

<div class="c012081 c01912">
    <label class="c01914 c012082 c01913" tabindex="-1">
        <input class="c01917" type="radio" value="leaveAsIs">
        <div class="c01918" data-qa-name="inspection-panel-warning-leave-as-is" data-qa-checked="true">
            <svg class="c01920 c0189 c0192" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8,1.33333333 C11.68,1.33333333 14.6666667,4.32 14.6666667,8 C14.6666667,11.68 11.68,14.6666667 8,14.6666667 C4.32,14.6666667 1.33333333,11.68 1.33333333,8 C1.33333333,4.32 4.32,1.33333333 8,1.33333333 Z M8,13.3333333 C10.9466667,13.3333333 13.3333333,10.9466667 13.3333333,8 C13.3333333,5.05333333 10.9466667,2.66666667 8,2.66666667 C5.05333333,2.66666667 2.66666667,5.05333333 2.66666667,8 C2.66666667,10.9466667 5.05333333,13.3333333 8,13.3333333 Z M8,11.3333333 C6.15905083,11.3333333 4.66666667,9.84094917 4.66666667,8 C4.66666667,6.15905083 6.15905083,4.66666667 8,4.66666667 C9.84094917,4.66666667 11.3333333,6.15905083 11.3333333,8 C11.3333333,9.84094917 9.84094917,11.3333333 8,11.3333333 Z"></path></svg>
        </div>
        <span class="c01921 c01921">Leave as is</span>
    </label>
    <label class="c01914 c012082 c01913" tabindex="-1"><input class="c01917" type="radio" value="fixForMe"><div class="c01918" data-qa-name="inspection-panel-warning-fix-for-me" data-qa-checked="false"><svg class="c01920 c0189 c0192" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8,1.33333333 C4.32,1.33333333 1.33333333,4.32 1.33333333,8 C1.33333333,11.68 4.32,14.6666667 8,14.6666667 C11.68,14.6666667 14.6666667,11.68 14.6666667,8 C14.6666667,4.32 11.68,1.33333333 8,1.33333333 Z M8,13.3333333 C5.05333333,13.3333333 2.66666667,10.9466667 2.66666667,8 C2.66666667,5.05333333 5.05333333,2.66666667 8,2.66666667 C10.9466667,2.66666667 13.3333333,5.05333333 13.3333333,8 C13.3333333,10.9466667 10.9466667,13.3333333 8,13.3333333 Z"></path></svg></div><span class="c01921 c01921">Fix for me</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I have been trying something along the lines of:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button[type='radio']")].find(function (ele) {return ele.innerText === "inspection-panel-warning-leave-as-is"})).click();
```

or

```
document.querySelector("radio[type='radio'][data-qa-name='inspection-panel-warning-leave-as-is']").checked = true;
```

I am sure there is a pretty simple solution but after repeated attempts, I just can't get it to work.

The last part is that I would like to set a delay in seconds, or until the next page loads to click the next button (using the first code sample). If I could get that it would put it all together. I am really hoping someone can help me out with this. This is such an awesome community. Thank you in advance for the assistance. I love trying to put these things together.

Comment: Why do you search for `button[type='radio']` or `radio[type='radio']` when you have `<input class="c01917" type="radio"` ?

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. If I had a good answer to that, maybe I could figure this out. I am a novice by all means and am trying to learn, but really don't know too much. I have no reasoning behind what I put together, it's more of what I can put together that will actually work. I am a long way from writing efficient code. I am lucky if the code does what I want. I usually can keep trying and get something. But here, I am stuck.

Comment: If you want to check a radio input, select the input element and simply set its `checked` property to true. `[data-qa-name='inspection-panel-warning-leave-as-is']` is not an input element, that's why you second solution didn't work. Do you mean you want to perform that on the actual radio input element before it?

Comment: well if the element which is of type `radio` is an `input`. why do you search for `button` or `radio` ? Try searching and learning about CSS/Javascript selectors.

Comment: @Terry I am looking to have a the radio selected so that I can click the next element. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you're confusing the two elements: the element that matches `[data-qa-name]` is NOT a radio button. If you want to change the value of the radio button, you need to select the radio button, and not that decorative `<div>` element after it.

Comment: @Terry Thank you. That is simple enough for me to understand.

Comment: I have tried ```document.getElementsByClassName("c01921")[0].click();``` and that won't do it. I have tried @Robert's suggestion and that won' work. I have tried to click the text "Leave as is" but can't seem to get the syntax ```document.querySelector('data[data-value*="Leave as is"]').click();``` What is wrong with the last incantation?

Comment: Another attempt I have tried is ```document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']").find(function (ele) {return ele.innerText === "Leave as is"})).click();``` and this too is not working.

Comment: I know I am really grasping at straws here. Another attempt: ```document.querySelector("input[type='radio'][data-qa-name='inspection-panel-warning-leave-as-is']").click();```

Answer (score 0):

### Using the correct selector

Your radio is an `input` element, with a type of radio, `<input class="c01917" type="radio" value="leaveAsIs">`

In your selector, you are trying to find a `button` element or even some type of `radio` element.

What you need in your selector is to find the `input` with a type of radio and optionally the class for greater specificity `document.querySelector('input[type="radio"].c01917')`.

```js
const radio = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"].c01917');
radio.checked = true;
```

```html
<div class=-"c012081"

<div class="c012081 c01912">
    <label class="c01914 c012082 c01913" tabindex="-1">
        <input class="c01917" type="radio" value="leaveAsIs">
        <div class="c01918" data-qa-name="inspection-panel-warning-leave-as-is" data-qa-checked="true">
            <svg class="c01920 c0189 c0192" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8,1.33333333 C11.68,1.33333333 14.6666667,4.32 14.6666667,8 C14.6666667,11.68 11.68,14.6666667 8,14.6666667 C4.32,14.6666667 1.33333333,11.68 1.33333333,8 C1.33333333,4.32 4.32,1.33333333 8,1.33333333 Z M8,13.3333333 C10.9466667,13.3333333 13.3333333,10.9466667 13.3333333,8 C13.3333333,5.05333333 10.9466667,2.66666667 8,2.66666667 C5.05333333,2.66666667 2.66666667,5.05333333 2.66666667,8 C2.66666667,10.9466667 5.05333333,13.3333333 8,13.3333333 Z M8,11.3333333 C6.15905083,11.3333333 4.66666667,9.84094917 4.66666667,8 C4.66666667,6.15905083 6.15905083,4.66666667 8,4.66666667 C9.84094917,4.66666667 11.3333333,6.15905083 11.3333333,8 C11.3333333,9.84094917 9.84094917,11.3333333 8,11.3333333 Z"></path></svg>
        </div>
        <span class="c01921 c01921">Leave as is</span>
    </label>
    <label class="c01914 c012082 c01913" tabindex="-1"><input class="c01917" type="radio" value="fixForMe"><div class="c01918" data-qa-name="inspection-panel-warning-fix-for-me" data-qa-checked="false"><svg class="c01920 c0189 c0192" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8,1.33333333 C4.32,1.33333333 1.33333333,4.32 1.33333333,8 C1.33333333,11.68 4.32,14.6666667 8,14.6666667 C11.68,14.6666667 14.6666667,11.68 14.6666667,8 C14.6666667,4.32 11.68,1.33333333 8,1.33333333 Z M8,13.3333333 C5.05333333,13.3333333 2.66666667,10.9466667 2.66666667,8 C2.66666667,5.05333333 5.05333333,2.66666667 8,2.66666667 C10.9466667,2.66666667 13.3333333,5.05333333 13.3333333,8 C13.3333333,10.9466667 10.9466667,13.3333333 8,13.3333333 Z"></path></svg></div><span class="c01921 c01921">Fix for me</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Robert. This seems to be the ticket although it is not working. Is there a way to use the data-qa-name instead of the class (which seems to be dynamic).

Comment: The radio input `<input class="c01917" type="radio" value="leaveAsIs">` doesn't have a `data-qa-name` attribute to it in the example you provided. Is it a different element you are attempting to select?

Comment: Here is a good reference from CSS-Tricks for selecting [attributes](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/)

Comment: @Peter When I input the script as written: ```const radio = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"].c01917');
radio.checked = true;``` it is not changing the status of the radio. I incorrectly, thought I could attempt to change ``data-qa-checked``` to true.  I will look at the link you provided. Thank you.